# All Sub crystal Report bind with same data

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports, I bind a **main report** with **year, paper, subject** and in a **sub report** I show books related to that **year and paper**.

My problem is that in the sub report, I'm seeing the same data for each paper. I use this data table in one data set.

I'm using the following code:

```
string query = "Select subjectname ,subjectnamehindi,year,  Paper ,  bookID  From paper  where unistrID='" + uniid  + "' order by year,Optional,paper";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataAdapter  da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet dsp = new DataSet();

da.Fill(dsp, "Main");
if (dsp.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
{
    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("Crys.rpt"));
    rpt.SetDataSource(dsp.Tables[0]);

    //Get sub report and assign datatable1 to that report 
    foreach (ReportObject repOp in rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects)
    {
        if (repOp.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
        {
            string SubRepName = ((SubreportObject)repOp).SubreportName;
            ReportDocument subRepDoc = rpt.Subreports[SubRepName];
            i = 0;
            c = dsp.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            DataSet dsp1 = new DataSet();
            while (c > 0)
            {
                string bookid = dsp.Tables[0].Rows[i]["bookID"].ToString();

                query = "SELECT BookCode,  dbo.PaperBook.SalePrice, BookName, DisplayAuthorName FROM dbo.MasterTitle INNER JOIN dbo.PaperBook ON dbo.MasterTitle.BookCode = dbo.PaperBook.BookCode where bookID='" + bookid + "'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(dsp1, "Sub");
                subRepDoc.SetDataSource(dsp1.Tables[0]);
                c = c - 1;
                i = i + 1;                   
            }              
        }
    }

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    // Assign report to the crystal report viewer      
}
```

How can I get the subreport to display the correct data for each paper?

Comment: Can you include some portion of your results in your question?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but your report may be generating a cartesian product between `year` and `paper`.

Answer (score 0):

2 Things to try:

1)  Clear the existing datasources before setting the subreport datasource:

```
subRepDoc.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
```

2)  Use a unique name for the dataset tables:

```
da.Fill(dsp1, "UNIQUENAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to filter your sub-report by the year and paper, and bind the tables again how you like them in the sub-report.